# Doctrine MongoDB ODM load referenced documents

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine

my szenario in detail, iv'e got one User Document:

```
/** @Document(collection="user") */
class User
{
    /** @Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Pet") */
    private $pet;

    public function getPet()
    {
        return $this->pet;
    }
}
```

and iv'e got one Pet document:

```
/** @Document(collection="pet") */
class Pet
{
    /** @Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User") */
    private $user;

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

A many to many correlation. If i call the following code for an existing document...

```
$result = $this->_dbContainer->getDocumentManager()->getRepository('User')->findBy(array('id' => => 'XZTZHJ323LKFHGJKLHGFGHJK'));
print_r($result->toArray());
```

...it ends in an endless loop. Error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 112721921 bytes) in ...
```

If i execute the following code:

```
var_dump($result->count());
```

The result ist one / it exist (everything ok). A var_dump of $result->current() is NULL. The method getMongoData returns the following data (which is correct):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [$ref] => example [$id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 4ddac7667294c79e17000002 ) [$db] => test ) )
```

If i execute the following code:

```
var_dump($result->current());
```

The result is boolean (false).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your model looks something like this

```
/**
 * @Document
 */
class User
{
    /** @Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Something") */
    private $somethings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->somethings = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getSomethings()
    {
        return $this->somethings;
    }
}
```

You should be able to retrieve the referenced models using

```
$user = $dm->find('User', $id);
$somethings = $user->getSomethings();
$firstSomething = $somethings->current(); // will return false if empty, can also use first()
foreach ($somethings as $something) {
    // and so on
}
```

Do not attempt to `var_dump()` or `print_r()` the model proxy objects. These contain many recursive references and you will exhaust your available memory attempting to render them as output.

Comment: Sorry but it don't work for me, my property has the following comment (same document structure like your example) /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="ExampleReferencedDocument") */ - the result iterator->count() says "1" (that it got one result) but if i want to get it with current i just get NULL?

Comment: There is some problem with the Doctrine Layer...

If i call the toArray() method in PersistentCollection result the script terminate and i found the following message in the error log:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size exhausted...

Inserts to the database works without any problem, damn.

Comment: @Stephan I've updated my answer, changing it to a `ReferenceMany` model and added some more information, particularly regarding `var_dump()`

Comment: First, thanks a lot Phil for your support! :) Unfortunately the changes dont ends in success, i forgot to init the ArrayCollection in the constructor but the result of $pet->current() is false and at the same time the $pet->count() returns 1 - a pet also exist in database with the correct references... im happy about any other suggestion!

Comment: @Stephan What happens if you try `first()` instead of `current()`?

Comment: If i exec the following code:

`// get a single pet object
$pets = $this->user->getPet();

var_dump($pets->count()); // returns 1  
var_dump($pets->current()); // returns FALSE
var_dump($pets->first()); // returns ENDLESS LOOP
  
foreach ($pets as $pet) {
   var_dump($pet->getName()); // outputs the name of the Pet!!! But how can i get the full object?
}`

Stephan

Comment: @Phil `var_dump($pets->first()); // returns an ENDLESS LOOP`

Comment: for dumping i suggest doing `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($variable)`
This is good for dumping doctrine objects in order to read it you can do a <pre> before it

Answer (score 1):

try regenerating hydrator classes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to get a single object from a referenced collection:

```
$pets = $this->user->getPets();     
if(!is_null($pets) && $pets->count() > 0) {
   $this->pet = $pets->first();
}
```

Biggest learning (thanks to @Phil):

> Do not attempt to var_dump() or
>   print_r() the model proxy objects.
>   These contain many recursive
>   references and you will exhaust your
>   available memory attempting to render
>   them as output.

Best regards,
Stephan